# WinForm: control won't add to a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, addition

On a WinForms, I'm trying to add a control (here a simple label) to a panel each time I click a button.
The UI looks like this:
[image: at start]

when I first click the button, I got this (what I expect!):
[image: after first click]

but, after a second, a third, etc. click, nothing more happens; no labels are added anymore :(

However, I can see them in the list of controls when I'm in debug mode:
[image: I can see you!]

Here's my code (only the interesting stuff):

```
public partial class GestionPateFeuilletee : Form
{
    private List<Label> listeTours = new List<Label>();

    public GestionPateFeuilletee()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void boutonAjouterTour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point coordDepart = new Point(10, 160);
        int tabIndexDepart = 5;

        listeTours.Add(new Label());
        listeTours.Last().Name = "labelTour" + (listeTours.Count());
        listeTours.Last().Location = new System.Drawing.Point(coordDepart.X, coordDepart.Y + 30);
        listeTours.Last().TabIndex = tabIndexDepart + 1;
        listeTours.Last().Text = "labelTour" + (listeTours.Count());

        this.panelDescription.Controls.Add(listeTours.Last());
    }
}
```

Any idea?
And yes, I'm a beginner with WinForms...
Thanks!

Comment: Increase the height of your panel and check

Comment: Any chance they could be on top of each other since you add them all to the same point?

Comment: Dumb me, it was that: all at the same point! Concerning the height, the panel is taking almost all the space of the window (which is by default the size of the screenshot), so I thought it wasn't that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your panel height is fixed. Your controls are getting added to the panel. However they are getting hidden in the panel because of the panel height. You can either increase the panel height or put a vertical scroll in the panel / form to have the labels visible.

Also define the Y location based on the no. of labels

```
listeTours.Last().Location = new System.Drawing.Point(coordDepart.X, coordDepart.Y + ((listeTours.Count() + 1) * 30));
```

Comment: Same thing that [sami](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3279876/sami): the problem was indeed because of the location. I will also take the vertical scroll in consideration, thank you!